# How to get all values for a customfield in JIRA?

Tags: java, rest, uri, jira

I've been basically working with this documentation to built my desired URI's in order to extract the information from a project, that I need: 
[JIRA REST API Reference](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/search-searchUsingSearchRequest)

However, now I have a customfield with the id **cf1** (example) and want to get a list (JSON response) of all the values that **cf1** might have.

For instance, with

> https://domain.com/jira/rest/agile/1.0/board/{boardID}/sprint

I can get all the sprints associated with the board. Can I do the same for a customfield?

Answer (score 2):

Use the createmeta call:

```
https://<your-jira-server>/rest/api/latest/issue/createmeta?projectKeys=<your-project-key>&issuetypeName=<your-issue-type-name>&expand=projects.issuetypes.fields
```

In the huge JSON thats returned, search for your custom field and read the allowedValues. Enjoy :)